# Forbidden, error 403 con Apache/2.4.6

Tags: linux, apache

Estoy configurando Apache/2.4.6 en un servidor Centos 7. He creado un virtual host de la siguiente manera:

```
<VirtualHost {IP}:80->
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/monkey/site/public
    ServerName www.monkey.net:80
    ServerAlias monkey.net
    ErrorLog /home/monkey/error.log
    CustomLog /home/monkey/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Además, (según yo) establecí una directiva para permiter a apache el acceso a dicha carpeta:

```
<Directory "/home/monkey/site/public">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Sin embargo, a la hora de ingresar a monkey.net  me da el siguiente error en el navegador:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Procedí a hacer algunos cambios a ver si le daba solución, pero el error aún sigue ahí:

1. Dar permisos de escritura y lectura a `/home/monkey/site/`  a `/home/monkey/site/public` con un `chmod 755`/`777`.
2. Establecer el tipo de directorio de `site/` con el comando:

   ```
   chcon -h system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /home/monkey/site/public
   ```

Observando los logs veo que el error se detalla de la siguiente manera:

> [core:error] [pid 7925] (13)Permission denied: [client 186.15.110.196:56917] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/monkey/site') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path

Googleando, básicamente lo que recomiendan es hacer lo que ya he hecho, pero sin resultados positivos. No sé si estaré pasando algo por alto. Saludos

**Edición 29/01/2016**:
SELinux parece no ser una barrera, puesto que `/var/log/audit/audit.log` no muestra mensajes de "access denied". Esto lo puedo comprar haciendo:

```
# ausearch -m AVC --start today -i
```

En cuanto al permiso de los directorios, he aplicado 644 a todos los directorios hasta el root:

```
// 755 /home/monkey/site/public/index.php
4 -rwxr-xr-x  index.php

// 644 /home/monkey/site/public/
0 drw-r--r-- 4  public

// 644 /home/monkey/site/
0 drw-r--r-- 4  site

...
```

Comment: el error que describes lo tomaste del log : /var/log/apache/error.log ? de lo contrario podrías indicar que error es guardado en ese log.

Comment: @Elenasys, lo tomé del error log especificado en el virtual host.

Comment: Revisa en el log de tu servidor apache, por el error pienso que solo requieres credenciales/permisos, en mi caso yo no tenia permisos "Read" sobre el folder.

Comment: En efecto hice las dos cosas.  El error log principal no deja errores,  y procedí a darle permisos coml ves en el post.  Y nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando el tema de la reputación, en general, al estar dentro del home, es necesario aplicar permisos de ejecución a los otros usuarios de la máquina. Las veces que he tenido este problema, lo soluciono así:

```
chmod o+x /home/monkey/site/public
chmod o+x /home/monkey/site
chmod o+x /home/monkey
chmod o+x /home
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisando acerca de tu error: [**AH00035 access denied because search permissions are missing on a component of the path**](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/13PermissionDenied)

> Tipicamente los permisos en un sistema Unix para los recursos que no son
>   propiedad de la usuario o grupo especificado en httpd.conf sería **644**
>   **-rw-r--r--** para archivos ordinarios y **755 drwxr-x-r** x para los directorios o scripts CGI. Puede ser necesario
>   para comprobar permisos extendidos (tales como permisos de
>   SELinux) en sistemas operativos que los soportan.

necesitas ademas de aplicar los permisos con

```
chmod 755
```

**debes realizar para los directorios:**

```
chmod 644
```

**644 significa que los archivos tienen permisos lectura y escritura por el propietario del archivo y de lectura 
por los usuarios en el propietario del grupo de ese archivo y legible por todos los demás.**

Comment: Hice dos cosas: 1. Lo que detallas acá, y es todo siguió igual (edité la pregunta con el resultado). 2. Reestablecí el archivo `httpd.conf` y eso hace que el index.php dentro de `/var/www/html/` cargue correctamente en el navegador. A pesar de que puedo entonces trabajar en esa carpeta no quiero dar este problema por esquivado. 
Por lo tanto, asigné la directiva de `DocumentRoot` a `/home/monkey/site/public/` y el problema de los permisos volvió.

Answer (score 0):

El apache 2.4 tiene algunos cambios en la configuración de los permisos de los direcorios, revisa https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/upgrading.html para más detalles

Answer (score 0):

Un buen punto de partida es mirar el LOG de ERROR

para Apache 2.4 (y para arriba)

```
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Mi archivo *mi-dominio.conf* en */etc/apache2/sites-available*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin mi-mail@gmail.com
    ServerName mi-dominio.com
    ServerAlias www.mi-dominio.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/mi-dominio.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /srv/mi-dominio.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /srv/mi-dominio.com/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /srv/mi-dominio.com/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Hay mucha confusion, la mayoría de los tutoriales siguen mostrando como se configura para **Apache 2.2**

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```